# How to optimize this code for Updating the UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to do expensive operations on secondary thread and I am new on that. So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am using GCD to design the cell and adding it on `contentView`.

I am using the below method to design the cell

```
-(UIView *)designCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath size:(CGSize)aSize
{
    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, aSize.width, aSize.height)];
    ....
    //design the cell with lots of UI elements
    ....
    return backView;
}
```

I had tried below but the cell is updating after a long time (approx. 8-9 secs) but 3 logs are printing in console instantly.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("threadToDesignCell", NULL);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        NSLog(@"queue interval1- %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
        UIView *cellContentView = [self designCellAtIndexPath:indexPath size:[cell frame].size];
        NSLog(@"queue interval2- %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog(@"queue interval3- %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
            [[cell contentView] addSubview:cellContentView];
            //[cell setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
```

I had also tried below but same problem arise like above.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"queue interval1- %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
        UIView *cellContentView = [self designCellAtIndexPath:indexPath size:[cell frame].size];
        NSLog(@"queue interval2- %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog(@"queue interval3- %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
            [[cell contentView] addSubview:cellContentView];
            //[cell setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
```

In Log

```
2015-03-13 12:52:46.515 TableDesigner[2262:65363] queue interval1- 1426231366.515081
2015-03-13 12:52:46.609 TableDesigner[2262:65363] queue interval2- 1426231366.609620
2015-03-13 12:52:46.914 TableDesigner[2262:65326] queue interval3- 1426231366.914309
```

Please help me understand what exactly happening wrong here.

Comment: UI updates must be done in main thread only

Comment: Yes I read that.. but what should I do in this case?

Comment: Currently I an designing the cell in Main Thread but as this operations taking time so tableview scrolling slowly. That's why I looking for that.

Comment: Your title to this question is incorrect isn't it? First you can't update the UI on a secondary thread it has to be the main thread. But what it seems like you are asking it how to optimize this code. Is that correct?

Comment: @Popeye you can change the title.

Answer (score 0):

1. to answer the question based on title alone:
   You can't update the UI from a secondary thread

---

Ill go out on a limp and claim that your 'designCellAtIndexPath' also accesses the UIKit -- 99% of that isn't thread-safe and should be done only on main thread. :)

so try this pointless code and if you don't suffer the enormous delay, thats it

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         UIView *cellContentView = [self designCellAtIndexPath:indexPath size:[cell frame].size ];            
         [[cell contentView] addSubview:cellContentView];
    });
});
```

### TODO: rewrite your designCellAtIndexPath and split it in 2 methods. 1 for doing the computation, 2. for doing the UI related work

Comment: yes firstly I did that but it's blocking the main thread. When the number of cell increased tableview scrolling slowly.

Comment: And doing this like calling `designCellAtIndexPath` on main thread directly.

Comment: I know thats the point of what I said -- ui can't access most of UIKit safely in bg

Comment: I added a TODO sentence as well.

Comment: `designCellAtIndexPath` approx. all the line accessing UIKit. I couldn't find for any code to split it.

Comment: then do it less often and for less cells. are you creating new views all the time? if so: don't ;) allocing and adding a view is expensive, do proper cell & view reusing

Comment: Actually there are 5 loops which creating UI elements. And each loop can be iterate upto 1000 times. In this case how I separate them into two methods?

Comment: I'd just try to reuse the content views -- allocating more views during scrolling _will_ lag